# Sencha Touch 2 and SDK for PC

Tags: html, mobile, javascript-framework, sencha-touch-2

Looking at the website, there seems to only be a link to SDK for a MAC environment, will there be one for a PC environment shortly for the Sencha Touch 2 SDK?

Thanks

M

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch 2 is in its first developer preview. They have released SDK for MAC environment only. I am sure they will be releasing the Windows version by the final release. Here is my [discussion](https://twitter.com/#!/edspencer/status/123858410298023936) with Ed Spencer.

Comment: Any dates at all? weeks, months?